# jquery ajax not working with data field

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

When i submit a jquery ajax request without the data value, it works, when i submit it with the data value, nothing happens. I check if it works using firebug. I think its a simple mistake but i cant seem to figure it out. Please Help.

Here is the Jquery Code

```
var inputString = $("something").val();
var suggestions = $.ajax({
    url: "temp.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {valueInput : inputString},
    dataType: "html"
});
```

temp.php just has some simple code since I'm testing:

```
    echo "We got sumn here";
```

another thing is the suggestions variable is empty, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
    data: 'valueInput=' + encodeURIComponent(inputString),
```

### Update

`suggestions` is being set to the jqXHR object returned from the `$.ajax()` function. If you want to do work on the server-response then you need to set a `success` callback somehow. Here are two ways:

```
var inputString = $("something").val();
$.ajax({
    url      : "temp.php",
    type     : "POST",
    data     : 'valueInput=' + encodeURIComponent(inputString),
    dataType : "html",
    success  : function (serverResponse) {
        //you can now do work on the server-response, it's stored in the serverResponse variable
        alert(serverResponse);
    }
});
```

OR

```
var inputString = $("something").val(),
    suggestions = $.ajax({
    url      : "temp.php",
    type     : "POST",
    data     : 'valueInput=' + encodeURIComponent(inputString),
    dataType : "html"
});
$.when(suggestions).then(function () {
    //this is your callback function
});
```

I suggest the first method, the second is more advanced and is really only helpful if you want to wait for a set of AJAX requests to complete before doing something.

Comment: Hey, that works thanks, another issue. The suggestions variable is still empty even though the request is being sent through. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon I updated my answer to show how to use a callback function for your AJAX requests.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon You're Welcome. If you found this answer to be **the** answer to your question, I'd appreciate an Accepted-Answer-Vote.

Answer (score 1):

valueInput should be in quotes as it's a name. 'valueInput'

```
var inputString = $("something").val();
var suggestions = $.ajax({
    url: "temp.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'valueInput': inputString},
    dataType: "html"
});
```

Comment: I believe you only need quotes when there is an invalid character like a hyphen or something. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jasper I always use quotes. What if I have a variable by that name? better safe than sorry.

Comment: Well I do know that you can't use a variable to declare a key in an object when creating it with literal notation. `var key = 'val', obj = { key : 'val' };` will result in an object that looks like this: `{ key : 'val' }`, not `{ val : 'val' }`. To use a variable as a key you have to do it like this: `var key = 'val', obj = {}; obj[key] = 'val';` which results in an object that looks like this: `{ val : 'val' }`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass data in a form of query string. It should be something like a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5

You can use .serialize() method over jQuery object that has selected form elements or form tag. So, maybe this code shall be helpful.

```
var suggestions = $.ajax({
    url: "temp.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("something").serialize(),
    dataType: "html"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

data: JSON.stringify({'valueInput': inputString}),

in you data parameter.